# Breaking html pages into sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to include sections into a HTML page for example header and footer (like we do in ruby on rails). Header and footer are saved in two different HTML pages. I am trying to include them into all of my pages with jquery or javascript.

Below is my code but nothing seems to work.

This is the Page where I want to include the sections.

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#result" ).load( "sections/header.html #targetDiv" );
    });
</script>
```

header.html:

```
<nav id="targetDiv">
    <div>...</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried to look in the developer tools in your browser, to see if an error is reported.

Comment: I just checked it out. this is the error XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/address.../sections/header.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8706

Comment: Got it.. I was using google chrome. It just worked in firefox. Thanks!